# ASP.NET Live debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, browser

In [a video recently posted in YouTube](http://youtu.be/UzyoT4DziQ4?t=23m14s), Scott Hanselman is demonstrating a very useful feature where you can edit your ASP.net application in debug mode directly from the browser.

Is this feature currently available in Visual Studio? If Yes how to do it? If not is there any plugins or VS extensions that help doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `Browser Link` and you can download it from [here](http://www.vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink). the feature is called `Design Mode`

> Works like Inspect Mode but when you finally click a DOM element in
>   the browser, that element becomes editable. Any edits are transferred
>   into Visual Studio in real time to update the source file.

Here is a [demo](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-Toolbox-Web-Essentials-and-CSSCop) on how to use the plugin.

Check out [this](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/visual-studio-2013-web-editor-features-browser-link) short video by Scott Hansleman, that shows this feature.

Comment: Its called `Browser Link` from your link :)